# Atom, how to import PHP namespaces and classes on MAC

Tags: atom-editor

I would love to have in Atom a kind of alternative to the **Sublime Text** package 
**Php Companion** that allow importing **namespaces** and **classes**.

I'm trying to figure out how works this functionality in the **atom-autocomplete-php** plugin.

In the [Documentation](https://atom.io/packages/atom-autocomplete-php) there are this functionalities listed:

- Autocompletion of class names and automatic adding of use statements where needed.
- Add use statement of class under cursor (ctrl-alt-u)

So I aspect that when I need to import a class in my PHP file when I write use...
I would get a series of options, but the **composer packages** I have required are not listed in my list.

If I press **ctrl-alt-u** or **ctrl-cmd-u** nothing happens.  (**I'm using a MAC**)

How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that there is some sort of incompatibility for the pre-defined key bindings on OsX.

I have solved re-mapping the key bindings for the autocomplete **namespace** and for the **import-use-statements**

Now instead of **ctrl-alt-u** and **ctrl-alt-n** i have re-mapped to **cmd-alt-u** and  **cmd-alt-n**.

To do that:

1. Open **Atom > Preferences > Keybindings**.
2. Create a personal Keymap file clicking on "your keymap file".
3. Added this code in the file.

This is the code:

```
'atom-text-editor':  
  'cmd-alt-u': 'atom-autocomplete-php:import-use-statement'
  'cmd-alt-n': 'atom-autocomplete-php:namespace'
```